# Please Explain $$v++ Why its returning 1 or true

Tags: php

```
<?php

function firstDuplicate($a) {
    foreach ($a as $v)
        echo $$v++;
    return -1;
}
firstDuplicate([2, 1, 3, 5, 3, 2]);
```

I'm unable to understand why echo $$v++ is returning 1. Please help.

Comment: I'm more curious what you think [that code](https://3v4l.org/9sV9S) actually does? Did you write it with a specific intention or find it somewhere?

Comment: I've to find first duplicate entry in array from database values. I found this code but can't understand $$v++ how its finding first duplicate.

Comment: Where did you find this code? Any code you find you should assume it doesn't work unless you know that it works. Did you run this against your database and it did in fact find the first duplicate?

Comment: Yes It's working perfectly but, I'm just curious about the $$ reference variable how its incrementing and finding duplicated entries?

Comment: That function will always, always, always return `-1`. Always, always, always. It will `echo` stuff, too, but that's not the same as a `return`.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Yes, the point they were asking was why it echos 1 in certain cases. _why echo $$v++ is returning 1_.  Bad use of word there.

Comment: Yeah, I get what they are literally saying, but they are also saying that it works perfectly, so I'm a little suspect on the actual question.

Comment: @ChrisHaas It's echoing the number of duplicates.  So if you were to add 2 to that array it would echo 1 and 2, so 2 duplicates 2s even though there are 3 2s.  I assume that's what they mean by _working_.

Comment: I'm curious what value the echo to a dataset `firstDuplicate([2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2 ])` would provide. I hope this is isn't used in production anywhere!

Comment: @ChrisHaas as expected https://3v4l.org/24A9v

Comment: I have no idea how anyone could find that useful! But I'll leave this alone because it is working perfectly for the OP at least!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through the loop it creates variables `$2, $1, $3, $5`, but they don't exist, so they don't `echo` as they are `null` and generate:

> Warning: Undefined variable

However, `$$v++` initializes them and increments them to `1` AFTER the `echo`.  Later in the loop, `$3` and `$2` do exist so they `echo` `1` and are incremented to `2` AFTER the `echo`.

So you get 4 *Warnings* and then `1` for the second occurrence of `$3` and `1` for the second occurrence of `$2`.

If you look at [Incrementing/Decrementing Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php#language.operators.increment) you will see that `$v++` is *Post-increment*, so it increments AFTER the evaluation.

See [the output](https://3v4l.org/evm6X).  See [Post-increment output](https://3v4l.org/8JFe5).  See [Pre-increment output](https://3v4l.org/eElnf).

**NOTE**: You can't define a variable starting with a number like `$1 = 'test'` but it does work when using variable variables when `$v = 1`, like `$$v = 'test` or  `${$v} = 'test'` and even `${1} = 'test'`.

When I originally started this answer I was focused on the variable names, but then it turned into pre-increment vs. post-increment so there may be a duplicate.

Comment: The purpose of this code was to find the first duplicate in the array. But I still can't understand why $$v++ only occurs at the number which is duplicate. Could you please explain $$v++ a bit more. Maybe this sounds silly but my mind is still stuck with this.

Comment: $v++ is Post-increment, so it increments after the echo https://3v4l.org/8JFe5

Comment: I do get that post-increment but with $$ reference variable how its finding the duplicated array elements?

Comment: The first time through the loop it creates a variable named `$2` and echos it (its null so no output), then it increments it by 1.  Then later the sixth time through the loop it echos `$2` which is 1.

Comment: Thank You so much for the explaination. You were so patient and generous. Appreciate that.

Comment: Glad to help.  I learned something about the numeric vars and I've been doing PHP for 20 years.  Please mark as accepted if it solved your issue.